# nr of cells between cells

Tags: grass-gis, distance

I want to do the following: I have a set of cells with the value 1, and a set of values with 2. I want to calculate for each cell [2] the distance - ideally number of cells - to the nearest cell [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjV6s.jpg). Can I somehow do this in GRASS GIS?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution: use r.grow.distance. Use a raster with [1] as value and the area of [2] as "no data". The resulting raster shows the distance of cells in the [2] are to the nearest cell [1], as manhattan, euclidean, maximum, etc.